Why doesn't C# cast Container<Derived> to Container<Base> implicitly?
Consider the following code snippet:
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal {}

interface IMyContainer<T> {
    T Get(int i);
    void Add (T thing);
}

class MyList<T> : IMyContainer<T> {
    private List<T> items = new List<T>();
    public T Get(int i) { return items[i]; }
    public void Add(T item) { items.Add(item); }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IMyContainer<Dog> dogs = new MyList<Dog>();

    // Why doesn't this cast dogs to animals?
    IMyContainer<Animal> animals = dogs;
    animals.Add(new Animal());
    Animal retrievedAnimal = animals.Get(0);
    animals.Add(new Dog());
}

I know the above C# will fail because generics are invariant. I know the line IMyContainer<Animal> animals = dogs; will fail because, even in situations where you may refer to a MyList<Dog> as a IMyContainer<Animal> (where the container is covariant), it is still a MyList<Dog> and the misleading reference might get users to add a Cat to a MyList<Dog>, which is why in such a case the interface cannot contain methods that accept  T.
My question is: Why doesn't the compiler simply cast the dogs object to a IMyContainer<Animal> when the reference is changed? It makes logical sense to me, and from that point forward the reference appropriately points to an object of the correct type and we are free to add and remove any Animals from our container. It seems all the type issues arise when we use a reference to refer to an object that is a subset of the reference type but not equal to it. Is such a cast impossible for the compiler to infer implicitly?

If it was just a normal generic list then you could easily do dogs.Cast<Animal>().ToList() to obtain a new list of animals, if that's what you want. Having the compiler automagically decide that is the right thing to do isn't something most people would want or desire, and indeed in this case the compiler will not know how to create your new container type and populate it with appropriate references.

PLEASE use proper naming. Right now it seems you're trying to cast to a base class, not an interface. Covariance isn't possible with classes, it's possible with interfaces with the out keyword, eg IMyContainer<out T>. In fact, IEnumerable<out T> itself is covariant. Of course, once you do that Add will complain because you can't add a Cat to a MyList<Dog> even if you cast to IMyContainer<Animal>

If I'm reading your question correctly, you seem to be under a misconception as to what a cast actually is. You seem to think that casting actually changes the type of an object. It does not. It simply provides access to the same object via a reference of a different type. The word "cast" is used in the same sense as "to cast something in a different light", i.e. to look at the same thing in a different way. You say:

from that point forward the reference appropriately points to an object of the correct type and we are free to add and remove any Animals from our container

That would require the actual object to change from a MyContainer<Dog> to a MyContainer<Animal>, because you obviously can't add anything but a Dog to a MyContainer<Dog>. What you're talking about is a conversion, not a cast, and that is definitely not going to happen implicitly. How could it, given that the same object could still be referred to by another variable of the original type? That would require this:
var dogs = new MyContainer<Dog>();
MyContainer<Animal> animals = dogs;

to result in dogs referring to a MyContainer<Animal>, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Yes this is what I was confused about. I did mean a conversion, but I still don't understand why you cannot change from a Container<Dog> to a Container<Animal>. What do you mean, by "The same object could still be referred to by another variable of the original type", in my head the object would be converted and the original type would be forgotten. Is this conversion complicated and impossible?

Because you could then add a Cat to your dog list. Read about covariance and contravariance in context of generics.

I realize now that @jmcilhinney meant we have the original dogs reference and the new animals reference both pointing to the same object. Separately, I think I understand cases where you wouldn't want an implicit cast like this (in some of these cases there might not be two references, but an original reference of one type and the object which is now a container).

@MukundKS if you used proper interface naming people would point out you can have variant generic interfaces, eg IMyContainer<out T>. You can't add a Cat to a MyList<Dog> even if you cast to IMyContainer<Animal> though. These things are covered in Creating Variant Generic Interfaces
